# how to print v-string?

Tags: perl

how to print v-string?

```
our $VERSION = v2.1;
print "$VERSION\n\n";
```

prints smileys. 
`☻☺`

Comment: Are you using a Windows machine?  On my Mac (OS X 10.10.2, Perl 5.20.1), the output is 4 bytes, `0x02`, `0x01`, (or control-B, control-A) and two newlines.

Comment: Works as designed. https://metacpan.org/pod/perldata#Version-Strings

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I'm on windows machine. perl v5.18.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What do you mean by print v-strings?  What output do you want?

You could do this:

```
printf "%vd", $VERSION;  # prints "2.1"
```

or this:

```
print version::->parse($VERSION)->stringify; # prints "v2.1"
```

or this:

```
print version::->parse($VERSION)->normal; # prints "v2.1.0"
```

or this:

```
print version::->parse($VERSION)->numify; # prints "2.001000"
```

Or (best choice of all) you could just avoid using v-strings altogether.

Comment: I want to print `2.1`. First option can do it.

Comment: note that all but the first will take any form of version; the first will be very unhelpful if given a non-v-string version

Answer (score 3):

In Simpler terms, V-Strings are used to convert ASCII numbers to characters.

For example, if we need to print a string "car" using V-String, we need to lookup ASCII value for each character in ASCII table (http://www.asciitable.com/)

c = 99,a = 97,r = 114

So,

```
$var  = v99.97.114;
print("$var \n");
```

The above statement will print "car"